# Tree Node class - deallocation in the destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, tree

Is my destructor correct?  Does it properly deallocate the subtrees?

```
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD__TREE
#define HEADER_GUARD__TREE

#include <deque>


namespace Sandbox {
    class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        Node( Node* parent );
        virtual ~Node();

        Node* GetFirstChild();
        Node* GetChild( int index );
        Node* GetLastChild();

        void AppendChild( Node* child );
        void AddChild( Node* child ,int index );
        void RemoveChild( int index );

        int  GetIndex() { return _index; }
        void SetIndex( unsigned int index ) { _index = index; };
    protected:

    private:
        Node* _parent;
        int _index;
        std::deque<Node*>* _children;
    };
}

#endif // HEADER_GUARD__TREE

Node::Node(): _parent(NULL), _index(NULL), _children(NULL){
    _children = new std::deque<Node*>;
    _index = 0;
}
Node::Node( Node* parent ): _parent(parent), _index(NULL), _children(NULL){
    _children = new std::deque<Node*>;
    _index = 0;
    _parent->AppendChild( this );
}
Node* Node::GetFirstChild(){
    return _children->front();
}
Node* Node::GetChild( int index ){
    return _children->at(index);
}
Node* Node::GetLastChild() {
    return ( _children->back() );
}

void Node::AppendChild( Node* child ) {
    _children->push_back( child );
    unsigned int index = _children->size();
    child->SetIndex( index );
}
void Node::AddChild( Node* child ,int index ) {
    std::deque<Node*>::iterator i = _children->begin();
    i = i + index;
    _children->insert( i, child );
    child->SetIndex( index );
}
void Node::RemoveChild( int index ) {
    std::deque<Node*>::iterator i = _children->begin();
    i = i + index;
    _children->at(index)->~Node();
    _children->erase( i );
}
Node::~Node() {
    _parent = NULL;
    _index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i >= _children.size(); i++ ) {
        _children->at(index)->~Node();
    }
    _children->clear();
    delete _children;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not real C++ code.
This is C written with a couple of classes.

Pointers are dangerous and should rarely be used in code. C++ has moved away from C in this regard over the last decade and all pointers should be either wrapped in a smart pointer or be part of a container structure.

For this a technique called RAII has been introduced. This is the concept that creation and destruction of an object are linked within the objects lifetime thus allowing you to control resources even in the face of exceptions.

There are a couple of ways to fix the code.
The simplest technique is to just use std::unique_ptr (or std::auto_ptr if you are using C++03).

```
    Node( Node* parent );
```

Are you passing ownership of the parent?
No. You have a seprat constructor for no parent and ownership is not being passed as a result you should pass the parent by reference (if it has a parent it must not be NULL and must exist).

```
    Node( Node& parent );
```

All these methods that return pointer.
Should they?

```
    Node* GetFirstChild();
    Node* GetChild( int index );
    Node* GetLastChild();
```

If there is a possibility of NULL then yes, otherwise return a reference.

Here you are adding a child:

```
    void AppendChild( Node* child );
    void AddChild( Node* child ,int index );
```

But there is no indication you are passing ownership. The person reading the code has to know how the internals of how your class works. Otherwise they do not know if the pointer passed should be dynamically allocated or not. You need to make this knowledge explicit in the interface. Here I would pass a unique_ptr to indicate that you are passing ownership of the pointer into the node.

OK. Parent is allowed to be a pointer.

```
    Node* _parent;
```

You do not own the object and it is possible to be NULL. There is no responsibility for this node to clean up its parent.

`_children` should not be a pointer. It should be an object. Thus allows automatic cleanup and no requirement to manually create it. Also this simplifies the copy construction and assignment operator (that you have currently failed to define).

Secondly the container should not be holding pointer. Here you have an option either it should be a container of smart pointers, or it should be a container designed specifically to hold ownership of pointers (so that it can be done safely).

```
    // Option 1:
    std::deque<std::uniqur_ptr<Node>> _children;

    // Option 2:
    boost::ptr_deque<Node>            _children;
```

Personally I prefer option 2. As the contain provides access to the pointers as if they were normal objects. This makes writing functors and the interacting with the standard algorithms much easier.

Also I would question the use of deque over vector but that is a minor detail.
    };
}

#### Secondary Comments:

Do initialization in the initialization list. You sort of try to NULL everything in the initialization list. It is best to actually initialize them and have an empty body.

```
Node::Node(): _parent(NULL), _index(NULL),             _children(NULL){
                      ^^^^ OK       ^^^^ Questionable  ^^^^^^^^ Should be an object

Node::Node( Node* parent ): _parent(parent), _index(NULL),     _children(NULL){
                                    ^^^^^^ OK       ^^^^ Questionable
```

In the constructor that takes a parent you don't check your input for NULL

```
// If somebody passes a NULL parent then this is no good.
_parent->AppendChild( this );
```

The use of your functions should be consistent.

Getting the first and last children can be badly defined if the node has no children. But the generic GetChild() function will throw an exception if you try and retrieve a child from an invalid index. These two different behaviors makes using your code hard to be consistent. I would change these so that they all or none throw an exception.

```
Node* Node::GetFirstChild(){
    return _children->front();
}
Node* Node::GetLastChild() {
    return ( _children->back() );
}
Node* Node::GetChild( int index ){
    return _children->at(index);
}
```

Manually calling the destructor is wrong here:

```
_children->at(index)->~Node();
```

Unless you allocated the memory in some other way the used 'Placement New' you should not be calling the destructor manually. But nothing in your interface indicates that. So this should be a normal call to delete.

```
delete _children->at(index);
```

When inserting a child into the middle is it intentional to only set the index of the inserted child?

```
void Node::AddChild( Node* child ,int index ) {
    std::deque<Node*>::iterator i = _children->begin();
    i = i + index;
    _children->insert( i, child );

    // You set this node
    // But what about the nodes from index+x to the end.
    // Currently their internal index is unchanged.
    //     This could be intentional but it is hard to tell without a comment.
    child->SetIndex( index );
}
```

#### I would try something like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD__TREE
#define HEADER_GUARD__TREE

#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_deque.hpp>

namespace Sandbox {
    class Node;
    class Node {
        public:
            Node();
            // Removed the constructor that passes a parent
            // this has problems when you need to define who owns the object.
            // Thus safer to just remove the interface.
            virtual ~Node() {}

            Node& GetFirstChild();
            Node& GetChild( int index );
            Node& GetLastChild();

            Node& AppendChild(std::auto_ptr<Node> child );
            Node& AddChild(std::auto_ptr<Node> child ,int index );
            void RemoveChild( int index );

            int  GetIndex() { return _index; }
            void SetIndex( unsigned int index ) { _index = index; };
        protected:

        private:
            Node* _parent;
            int _index;
            boost::ptr_deque<Node> _children;
    };
}

#endif // HEADER_GUARD__TREE

using namespace Sandbox;

Node::Node()
    : _parent(NULL)
    , _index(0)
{
}

// All node child node access fails with an exception if the child is not there.
// Thus we always return a reference to the node
Node& Node::GetFirstChild()
{
    return _children.at(0);
}

Node& Node::GetChild( int index )
{
    return _children.at(index);
}

Node& Node::GetLastChild()
{
    return _children.at(_children.size() - 1);
}

// Inserting a node will return a reference to the node after insertion.
// The nodes are passed by std::auto_ptr to indicate transfer or ownership into the tree
// Note an empty auto_ptr inserted into the boost_deque will result in an exception so
// the node must have been created.
Node& Node::AppendChild(std::auto_ptr<Node> child )
{
    _children.push_back( child );
    unsigned int index = _children.size();

    _children[index].SetIndex(index);
    return _children[index];    
}

Node& Node::AddChild(std::auto_ptr<Node> child ,int index )
{
    boost::ptr_deque<Node>::iterator i = _children.begin();
    i = i + index;

    _children.insert( i, child );
    _children[index].SetIndex( index );
    return _children[index];
}

void Node::RemoveChild( int index )
{
    boost::ptr_deque<Node>::iterator i = _children.begin();
    i = i + index;

    _children.erase( i );
}
// Destruction is done automatically no code here.
```

Comment: really long answer so give me a minute to review but it looks awesome so far

Comment: the constructor taking a parent is there so i can assign a node to a given parent

Comment: // You set this node
    // But what about the nodes from index+x to the end.
    // Currently their internal index is unchanged.
    //     This could be intentional but it is hard to tell without a comment. 
 
Completely Unintentional

Comment: such a seemingly simple problem i might attempt to reimplement as a tree where the tree owns all the children and subchildren to eliminate things like parent pointers and such but idrk

Comment: the reason i Null out everything is more of a byproduct of me originally having another constructor that took both a parent and an index but i totally see your point

Comment: your also completely right about the way i called the destructor i guess i had a brain fart but none the less it did compile roflmao

Comment: the reason i used a deque instead of a vector is that when inserting into the middle its faster than a vector(or at least thats what i was told, srry cant site the reference)

Comment: so if in your implementation the tree owns the data wouldnt that leak memory because at most the deck is deallocated and not the deck of the subtrees or am i misunderstanding your implementation

Comment: the reason i used a pointer to a deck instead of the deck itself is in the case of the leaf it doesnt need a deck iirc a deck allocates a non 0 number of objects(basically to avoid reallocing on first use of the deck) and in that case there is extra memory being used for no reason

Comment: what you were saying about the index being updated wrong could lead to a case where 2 nodes point to the same index (yikes!)

Comment: ugh... so my insert method will take O(N - index) where n is the number of elements in the deck instead of constant time so to make that run fast i would have to implement some sore of binary search algorithm..... complexity here we come

Comment: @WorrynAshtrod: My implementation will not leak. All object will automatically clean up after themselves correctly destroying any dynamically allocated (owned ) object.

Comment: @WorrynAshtrod: The deque supports constant time insertion at the front/back but insertion into the middle is linear. See: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html and http://stackoverflow.com/q/181693/14065

Comment: @WorrynAshtrod: Worrying about the leaf not needing to hold children makes your code ten times more complicated. And the saving of space will be about 8 bytes (three pointers in deque - the pointer you are adding to point the deque => 12 - 4 = 8). Not a good trade.

Comment: .. Cont: If you really want to do that optimization I would wrap the children in their own class to handle the dynamic allocation. Its called the [`Seporation of Concerns`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) This basically means a class handles resource management or business logic **NOT** both. Applied to this case it means the `Node` class handles the tree and its interaction you need a seprate class to manage the resources associated with dynamic memory management. A simple rule of thumb: A class should contain no more than **ONE** owned pointer.

Comment: @WorrynAshtrod: The most important thing is to learn how to write code in a C++ style. This mean no RAW owned pointers in your class. Read about the concept of RAII. All owned pointers should be wrapped inside a smart pointer (or container) type class. A good place to start reading is std::shard_pointer/std::unique_ptr etc

Answer (score 2):

One thing Loki Astari hasn't covered is [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html), which your code is sorely lacking.  You should make anything that isn't going to change `const`, and mark all non-static member functions that don't modify the object they operate on as `const`, too.

For example, the declaration `Node( Node* parent );` should actually be `Node(Node const* parent);`, and the definition `int  GetIndex() { return _index; }` should be `int GetIndex() const { return _index; }`.

Further, I'm not sure making `_index` private is all that good an idea.  Are these nodes going to be used by one class, or many?  If only one class needs to be aware of them, you could choose to make them a nested class and expose more of them.  It probably won't matter for performance after inlining, though.  On the other hand, I see no reason at all to keep `_index` around, as it is only ever set to 0 when an instance is created, and then never touched again (until the destructor, but that's mostly redundant).

You should also watch out for variables that start with an underscore: if the underscore is followed by a copital letter, the name is reserved, and you should not use it.  If you insist on marking your member variables somehow, consider a `m_` prefix or an underscore suffix.